# React-native formik - very slow performance with several fields

Tags: react-native, formik

I have problem that performance of my formik is very slow if there is several fields, it works relatively slow with 4 fields but it was acceptable but since we have 12 it works definitely too slow. Marking checkbox takes approximately 3-4 seconds. Thing is that each click seems to rerender all fields. I tried to find how to fix it and one of the options was using FastField but unfortunately it seems to not working with RN. Any idea how to make it work faster and not rerender unnecessarily unchanged fields?

So basically each field contains 2 things:

- checkbox which check if textfield should be disabled or not
- textfield where user can type some amount by keyboard or by buttons

It looks like this:

```
<Formik innerRef={formRef} initialValues={updatedValues} validationSchema={validationSchema} onSubmit={() => {}}>
      <Box>
        <CheckboxWithInputControls
          checkboxFieldName={'addedPipeline'}
          inputFieldName={'pipeline'}
          label={t('additionals.pipeline')}
          step={amount}
        />

        <Divider />

        <CheckboxWithInputControls
          checkboxFieldName={'addedHose'}
          inputFieldName={'hose'}
          label={t('additionals.hose')}
          step={amount}
        />

        .....
        <FormChangesListener setIsValid={setIsValid} setValues={setValues} />
      </Box>
    </Formik>


export const CheckboxWithInputControls = ({
  checkboxFieldName,
  inputFieldName,
  label,
  step,
  inputRightElement
}: CheckboxWithInputControlsProps) => {
  const [{ value: isChecked }, _meta, { setValue }] = useField(checkboxFieldName)

  return (
    <Box mb="4">
      <Box my="2" p="2" bg={isChecked ? 'blue.100' : 'white'} borderRadius="md">
        <Checkbox
          value={checkboxFieldName}
          isChecked={isChecked}
          onChange={() => setValue(!isChecked, false)}
        >
          {label}
        </Checkbox>
      </Box>
      <Box pl="10">
        <NumberInputWithControls
          controlName={inputFieldName}
          disabled={!isChecked}
          step={step}
          inputRightElement={inputRightElement}
        />
      </Box>
    </Box>
  )
}

const FormChangesListener =({ setIsValid, setValues }:AdditionsFormProps) => {
  const { values, isValid } = useFormikContext()
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsValid(isValid)
    setValues(values as FormProps)
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [values, isValid])
  return null
}
```

Why-do-you-render response:

```
 GROUP    CheckboxWithInputControls
 LOG    {"CheckboxWithInputControls": [Function CheckboxWithInputControls]} Re-rendered because of hook changes:
 GROUP      [hook useContext result]
 LOG      different objects that are equal by value.
```

EDIT:
I made it works so here I leave solution, maybe it will be useful for someone or maybe someone would be able to provider better one as personally I dislike it
So turned out that useField somehow cause all form to be rerendered. when I gave up on idea of useField in CheckboxWithInputControls and just pass values via props it works fine and change in one field make only this one field to be rerendered.

```
{({ values, setFieldValue, touched, errors }) => (
        <Box>
          <CheckboxWithInputControls
            checkboxFieldName={'addedPipeline'}
            inputFieldName={'pipeline'}
            label={t('additionals.pipeline')}
            step={amount}
            value={values.addedPipeline}
            subValue={values.pipeline}
            setFieldValue={setFieldValue}
            touched={touched.pipeline}
            error={errors.pipeline}
          />
    )})
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find a problem is to use https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render or Flipper Flamegraph Tool. If you find that problem in a lot of unnecessary rerenders you can understand where to fix it.
From your implementation, first of all, try to remove the anonymous function from `onSubmit={() => {}}` because it causes rerendering to all child elements in every render cycle. Also try to add memorization for your custom component `CheckboxWithInputControls` with `memo(CheckboxWithInputControls)`

Comment: I need to keep onSubmit like that as it is obligatory property and otherwise typescript is yelling at me, I handle Submit in different place so that's why I keep it empty, also I already tried to embrace my components with memo but it did not bring any effect. I will try this "Why-did-you-render" and let's see what it tells me

Comment: let us know here about the results and it is not a problem to keep onSubmit, problem is that it is anonymous function, try to extract it

Comment: when I use memo then it shows nothing, without memo it gives me info like in my updated question,I guess it is caused my formListener but still, without it I can't update values